# .Net Runtime Not Downloading on Ubuntu Linux Server

Tags: c#, .net, linux, runtime

I coded a c# .Net 5 runtime console app, but the runtime will not download on my server.

I get the following error: The following .Net runtime is missing (.Net 5.0.8)

I am not sure how to install this specific runtime since I get a version not found.

Exact error:

```
The .NET runtime can be found at:
 - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=win7-x64&apphost_version=5.0.8


ALSO:
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-runtime-5.0.8
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-runtime-5.0.8'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-runtime-5.0.8'

``
```

Comment: How did you install the .Net runtime on your server? You can run `dotnet --list-runtimes` to see what's installed.

Comment: @gunr2171 Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.13 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13

Comment: the download link in your error says `rid=win7-x64` - which is curious on a _linux server_. could you please _edit_ your question and include how exactly you built & published the app?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I just built it via .net 5. Im not sure what you mean